# JavaFX resize text in chart axis

Tags: css, fonts, charts, javafx, axis

I currently have a bar chart, in which not all of X-Axis data is being displayed.

Here's a Screenshot:
[image]

I have searched the Internet thoroughly but I can not find a solution. I don't know what the css class for these text are and can not find it. When I change the -fx-font-size in any class in css, only the label font sizes are changed.

I would like to resize the x-axis text so that all of it can be displayed.

Rotating the texts would also work but I couldn't find a solution for that either.

PS:don't worry about the half German country names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can change the font size of the axis easily from code without css. I assume you have a category axis..

```
CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
xAxis.tickLabelFontProperty().set(Font.font(15));
```

or if you want it by css:

```
.axis{
  -fx-tick-label-font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try lowering font size

```
xAxis.setStyle("-fx-tick-label-font-size:0.6em;");
```

and then a little bit rotation  would do the job

```
xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to rotate:

```
<div style="width:5px; word-wrap:break-word; font-size: 12px;">
  GERMANY
</div>

 OR
```

Simply set font size as you need,

```
style=" font-size: 10px;
```